# Speed up looping over three axis' in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I need to speed up a `for` loop that does something like the code below:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.normal(size=(206,11,11))
y = np.random.normal(size=(206,11,11))
complx = x + 1j*y
complx

a,b,c = complx.shape

for n in xrange(a):
    #do somthing
    z = np.zeros(b) 
    for i in xrange(b):       
        z[i] = (complx[n,:,:].real[i][i]*complx[n,:,:].real[i][i] +\
                complx[n,:,:].imag[i][i]*complx[n,:,:].imag[i][i])(**-0.25)
```

I'm vaguely aware these things can sometimes be done with `numpy.einsum`.

However, i am not really sure how to use it?

Or does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: It's not exactly clear yet what you try to achieve. You use the index `i` in two different loops. Furthermore, you write `.real[i][i]`, but not `.imag[i][i]`. Can you clarify?

Comment: Do you want to speed up both `for` loops or only the inner one? Does `#do something` depend on n?

Comment: No, just the inner one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to speed up the inner `for` loop you can do something like this

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.normal(size=(206,11,11))
y = np.random.normal(size=(206,11,11))
complx = x + 1j*y

# takes only the diagonal part of all the 11x11 matrices
complx_diag = np.diagonal(complx,0,1,2)

# do the calc
zn = np.abs(complx_diag)**(-0.5)

for n in xrange(a):
    z = zn[n]
    # do your stuff
```

In case your `stuff` is not too complicated it can be vectorized as well (very likely).
The more you calculate outside the `for` loop the faster is your code.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, this is more or less what you want. The print statements are only there to convince oneself that the calculation is correct.

```
def optimize_01():
    x = np.random.normal(size=(6, 11, 11))
    y = np.random.normal(size=(6, 11, 11))
    complx = x + 1j * y

    a, b, _ = complx.shape

    for n in range(a):
        # do somthing
        A = complx[n, :, :]
        d = np.diagonal(A)
        z = np.power(np.abs(d * d), -0.25)

        print (d[0])
        print (z[0])
        print ((d[0].real * d[0].real + d[0].imag * d[0].imag) ** -0.25)
```

EDIT: If I compare this implementation with your implementation, I get the following.

```
import timeit

def optimize_02():
    x = np.random.normal(size=(206, 11, 11))
    y = np.random.normal(size=(206, 11, 11))
    complx = x + 1j * y

    a, b, _ = complx.shape

    for n in range(a):
        # do somthing
        A = complx[n, :, :]
        d = np.diagonal(A)
        z = np.power(np.abs(d * d), -0.25)

def optimize_03():
    x = np.random.normal(size=(206, 11, 11))
    y = np.random.normal(size=(206, 11, 11))
    complx = x + 1j * y

    a, b, _ = complx.shape

    for n in range(a):
        # do somthing
        z = np.zeros(b) 
        for i in range(b):       
            z[i] = (complx[n, :, :].real[i][i] * complx[n, :, :].real[i][i] + \
                    complx[n, :, :].imag[i][i] * complx[n, :, :].imag[i][i]) ** (-0.25)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print (timeit.timeit(optimize_02, number=10))
    print (timeit.timeit(optimize_03, number=10))
```

Result:

```
0.03474012700007734
0.09025639800074714
```

With 6 arrays of 1100 elements, instead of 206 arrays of 11 elements, the result is:

```
5.762741210999593
5.771216576999905
```

It looks like my solution is not as fast after all.